# What happens when t tends to infinity in the heat equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I have read that for the solution $u$ of the heat equation:

$$u_t(t,x) - \frac{1}{2} \nabla^2 u(t,x) =0, \\(t,x) \in (0, \infty)\times\mathbb{R}^n$$
$$u(0,x)=f(x), x \in \mathbb{R}^n$$

with $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n), n \in \mathbb{N}$

When time tends to infinity the u function tends to zero, but I don't know how to prove it, could someone help me?

Comment: That should be the Laplacian operator, not the gradient. Besides, this is not even always true (I can give examples where it is not).

Comment: This is true if $u_0\in L^2(\mathbb R^n)$. In that case you can write the unique $L^2$ in space solution as convolution with a Gaussian. From that explicit formula it is rather easy to conclude. (@K.defaoite: the term $\nabla^2$ stands for the Laplacian, that's a common notation in physics and applied sciences).

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I know, I edited it in. It was originally $\nabla$.

Comment: @K.defaoite It was $\Delta$ at the beginning, but at edit 2, the editor (Not the OP) made a mistake (you can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3899939/revisions))

Comment: @K.defaoite: Oh, I see, I didn't notice it was edited, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unique solution (assuming the usual reasonable growth conditions) is given by convolution with a rescaled version of the heat kernel:
$$
u(t,x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{e^{-|x-y|^2/(2t)}}{(2\pi t)^{n/2}}f(y) dy.
$$
Since $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ we can simply bound
$$
|u(t,x)| \le \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{1}{(2\pi t)^{n/2}} |f(y)| dy = \frac{1}{(2\pi t)^{n/2}} \Vert f \Vert_{L^1},
$$
and from this it's clear that $\lim_{t\to\infty} \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} |u(t,x)| =0$, i.e. the solution decays uniformly to zero as $t \to \infty$.

Comment: Yes, and it works only for solutions of this form. There are solutions to the heat equation that is not given by the heat kernel.

Comment: Uniqueness holds provided the solution is assumed to be bounded above by an inverse Gaussian.  This seems to be implied in the context of the question.